# Applying for a UK Spousal Visa from Moscow

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, russia

A spouse application has three parts: the passport, the form, and the supporting documents.

The procedure is that the applicant makes an appointment and reports to their cognisant application centre for their biometrics enrolment. What should they do with those various parts when they attend their appointment?  I.e., what is the applicant required to have at that time? And what happens to their stuff after their biometrics have been enrolled?

Comment: Gayot, did you intend to self-answer this originally?

Comment: @Gayot? As Jonathan asked? Currently you're asking multiple questions in one post as well...

Comment: @MarkMayo following the change of rules for spouses last year, this was meant to be a total freebie for any noob to help get themselves started at Expats. It's a great question because soon all spouses everywhere will have to follow the same model.